# Sorting Latest Magento Reviews By Date (For Homepage)

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, review

I'm trying to display the latest 10 review on the homepage. For some reason, they are not sorting by date.

```
$review = Mage::getModel('review/review');
$collection = $review->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->getSelect()->limit(10);
$review->appendSummary($collection);
```

If I print the SQL generated by `$collection->getSelect()`, I get the following:

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`,`e`.`name`, 
    `e`.`sku`, `rt`.`review_id`, `rt`.`created_at` AS `review_created_at`, 
    `rt`.`entity_pk_value`, `rt`.`status_id`,`rdt`.`title`, `rdt`.`nickname`, 
    `rdt`.`detail`, `rdt`.`customer_id`,`rdt`.`store_id` 
FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` 
    INNER JOIN `review` AS `rt` 
        ON rt.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id 
    INNER JOIN `review_detail` AS `rdt` 
        ON rdt.review_id = rt.review_id 
WHERE (e.status = 1) 
ORDER BY `e`.`created_at` DESC
```

Ended up changing the select to:

`$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
$reviews->addStoreFilter( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
      ->addStatusFilter( Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED )
      ->setDateOrder()
      ->addRateVotes()
      ->load();`

And the order is now fine....but somehow I lost the review summary. Star ratings I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `ORDER BY e.created_at DESC`. You're sorting by the `created_at` of the product table. Try removing your sort line, and replace it with `$collection->getSelect()->order('rt.created_at', 'desc')`. `rt` is the review table from looking at your query.

Comment: Same thing. No luck. Ended up changing how I selected reviews which worked. Updated question.